# JDBC to JTable output query regarding making buttons work in GUI Editor for Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, jbutton

so, i'm working on a project where I have to use a search button to find user information from a jdbc database, and so far I've got some of the code to work and added fields and data to the database, but once i hit search in the jtextfield it doesn't display any data in the table. So, i'm wondering if someone can take a look at this code and tell me where the mistake is, the jbutton is supposed to connect to the mainframe where the database connection information is stored.

this is the main frame code:

```
package guestbook;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Coolkidsclub;create=true;user=Vic";
public static Connection conn = null;
    /**
     * Creates new form MainFrame
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        try {
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();//"org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" to use derby driver
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
initComponents();
}
catch (Exception e){
}

        initComponents();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/guestbook/ckc.PNG"))); // NOI18N

        jButton1.setText("Add Kid");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Update Kid");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Remove Kid");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Find Kid");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(106, 106, 106)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(109, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(126, 126, 126)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton4)
                .addGap(130, 130, 130))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addComponent(jButton4))
                .addContainerGap(44, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        AddFrame add = new AddFrame();
              add.setVisible(true);
              this.dispose();
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        UpdateFrame update = new UpdateFrame();
            update.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        RemoveFrame remove = new RemoveFrame();
        remove.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        SearchFrame search = new SearchFrame();
search.setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

and this is the searchframe code:

```
package guestbook;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class SearchFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public SearchFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }
    public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
throws SQLException {
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
}
Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
while (rs.next()) {
Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
}
data.add(vector);
}
return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
}

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable2 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/guestbook/fckc.PNG"))); // NOI18N

        jTextField1.setText("Type Name Here...");

        jButton5.setText("Find Kid");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton6.setText("Go back to Start");
        jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "", "", "", ""
            }
        ));
        jTable2.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(113, 113, 113)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 518, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 383, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jButton5)))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(294, 294, 294)
                        .addComponent(jButton6)))
                .addContainerGap(146, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton5))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton6)
                .addContainerGap(58, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
Statement stmt = MainFrame.conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from COOLKIDS " + jTextField1.getText().toString());

jTable2.setModel(buildTableModel(rs));//to display the table
} catch (Exception except) {
}
    }                                        

    private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       MainFrame main = new MainFrame();
main.setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SearchFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SearchFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SearchFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SearchFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SearchFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm relatively new to java.

EDIT: After a day or two I did a stackTrace exception printout and it says something about the statement stmt code being wrong do i just need to add a line in the searchframe to connect to the database and forget the mainframe connection?

Comment: you really need to try and chop out at least 80% of the code in these examples. Only have code which is needed to repeat your error.

Answer (score 0):

> *So, i'm wondering if someone can take a look at this code and tell me where the mistake is, the jbutton is supposed to connect to the
>   mainframe where the database connection information is stored.*

Well the first thing I can say is it's a lot of code. Now, there are several conceptual mistakes in your code that may lead to the stated problem.

#### Don't mix View (user interface) with Database connections

Beware that applications are tipically designed using layers or levels to isolate and separate responsibilities. In this case having a static `Connection` object within a `JFrame` simply breaks this principle. The first thing to do is separate database connection and logic from the user interface.

#### Don't ignore exceptions, always give them a correct treatment

This one of the worse things we can do:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

If an exception has been thrown it means that something unexpected happened. Just ignoring the exception in an empty catch block won't make it be solved but will hide this fact to us. Consequently we won't be able to solve the problem because we don't actually know that something wrong is heppening.

#### Avoid using static references

If you need to use a static to access a class member then it's probably there's a design problem in our code. While static fields are possible and sometimes useful (i.e.: define constants) from an OOP point of view they are not a good choice because break the encapsulation principle. We can just give access to a class member to the outside by providing getters and setters.

---

> *EDIT: After a day or two I did a stackTrace exception printout and it says something about the statement stmt code being wrong do i just
>   need to add a line in the searchframe to connect to the database and
>   forget the mainframe connection?*

You would have to include the stack trace in your question, but let's take a look to the SQL query sent to the database:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from COOLKIDS " + jTextField1.getText().toString());
```

Most likely there is a `WHERE` clause missing in your SQL statmement (I don't know the text obtained from `jTextField1` so it's just a guess). SQL statments tipically have this minimal structure:

```
SELECT fields list
FROM tables
WHERE conditions
```

On the other hand you might consider use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM coolkids WHERE name = ?";
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Once again, this code should be isolated from the UI and `jTextField1` text should be passed as an argument to an appropriate Controller/Persistence layer class.

Comment: hey thanks for answering the question and trying to help i kind of solved the problem by including the connection code in the searchframe code so that it prints out the whole table when the button is pressed. This works, but doesn't allow for the text field, so i just changed the GUI to say that it displays a list of people from the database table. The original code i was given included the where clause but i wasn't sure where the where clause was supposed to come from. In any case, i'm happy with the outcome of my coding for now, I'll try this way soon. Thanks.